# Loading file from Firebase storage through selfLink gives 401

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I am putting files in Firebase Storage, and (using cloud functions) store the `objectMetaData.selflink` in the database. I am trying to load a file using that link, but get a 401 stating that:

> Anonymous users does not have storage.objects.get access to filename]

But since i am logged in (there is a `currentUser` on the `auth()` instance), i am confused what i am doing wrong here. Should i be sending some kind of token with my request?

I have not changed the initial ruleset for storage:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Also, maybe related but maybe not: since [this example](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files) uses another approach, what is the difference between `selfLink` and `getDownloadURL`?

**EDIT:**

I finally got it working by using `firebase.storage().ref(somePath)`. I also tried `firebase.storage().refFromURL(selfLink).getDownloadURL()` but that gave the error of supplying an invalid link to `refFromURL`. Then the question remains: what exactly is the selfLink?

Answer (score 0):

Documentation states that the `selfLink` is the link to access the object, assuming you have sufficient permissions. It is not the download URL

[Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/providers_storage_.objectmetadata.html#selflink)

Comment: @cheesussaysstopfiringmods I fixed the link. Have you tried OP's solution?